# "WARNING: Error in the metadata of the table ..." on opening database

Tags: ms-access, jdbc, metadata, ucanaccess

I'm getting a warning message like this when connecting to some databases:

> Error in the metadata of the table tblCourses: table's row count in the metadata is 69 but 37 records have been found and loaded by UCanAccess. All will work fine, but it's better to repair your database.

The records in my database were not all retrieve. I didn't know row count is gotten from metadata?

Anyone who knows how to solve this bug?

Comment: Can you include the data?  I suspect distinct / duplicates

Answer (score 8):

It's not a bug. UCanAccess is simply reporting that the row count in the metadata does not match the actual number of rows in the table. This is apparently due (at least in part) to some carelessness in the coding of Access, since one way to recreate the issue is to insert and delete rows from a table in Datasheet View in Access itself.

If you want the warning to go away then just open the database file in Access and perform a "Compact and Repair Database" operation.